# Image not showing up html css

Tags: html, css, image, tomcat

I have an image from my css that is set up to be the background. I am hosting the website on a tomcat 7 server

```
 body { 
        background: url("images.png") repeat 0 0;
    }

    body { 
        background-image: url("images.png") repeat 0 0;
    }
```

I have both in my css to try and get one to show up. It is in the right location i know that from debugging.
images.png
/Employee_12_14_13
GET
404
Not Found
text/html   is what i am getting in chrome. It is in that folder so im not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Try pulling the image from the exact location it is at, images.png is to general for your computer to analyze where exactly it could be. So be sure to include the path to get to your image.

Comment: I gave it the exact location as it was in the folder of the project on tomcat and also in a different folder that i had renamed and gave a full path to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a complete url for images.png ?

Answer (score 0):

Web Developer is right,
make sure you have a full path to the image directory and then to the image.

example..

```
background: url("images/myimage.png") repeat 0 0;
```

Check the directory its self..could it be a permissions issue? I use plesk as a server manager and I've had to add the Plesk user account to the list of users permitted to view/update a directory before.

Comment: I had it in the direct folder but now it is in the images folder within the project folder

Answer (score 0):

Declaring

```
background-image: url('images.png') repeat 0 0;
```

will cause the CSS to break. `background-image` property only accept one value which is the URL of the image. So you just need the first declaration

```
background: url('images.png') repeat 0 0;
```

Comment: Then the image path is wrong. If the image is located inside some folders then change the URL path into `background-image: url('path/to/image.png')`

Comment: ive updated the image path in two different ways still no luck. images/images.png and Employee_12_13_14/images/images.png

Comment: xp- Using eclipse to program and hosted on tomcat7

Comment: So you copied the exact folder location from the xp toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    background:url('urimage.jpg') repeat 0 0;  
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both image and .html are to be in same folder...

- create a folder.(say Showimage)
- place image in it.
- design a html page and save it as .html in that folder(Showimage) which you have created earlier where the image is already resided.
- Execute it...

Surely U'll get the image on your browser.